# Applying Textblob to dataframe returns characters instead of textblob object

Tags: python, textblob

I am trying to apply textblob like so:

```
df['newtext'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x))
```

but that tokenizes "text" and returns (I, ', v, e, , b, e, e, n, , u, s, i, n, g,...) instead of a textblob object.
Any idea why this is so?

Comment: We can join it again like this... "".join(TextBlob(x)) ... nah?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately when you are using the apply method, you are returning a TextBlob object instead of a String and Pandas doesn't know exactly what to do with it (which is why you get the weird behavior)

To solve your issue, simply surround the object being returned by TextBlob with `str()`, and it will work. Check the below example

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

d = {'text': ["I'm learning", "I love coding"], 'num': [2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

df['newText'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x:str(TextBlob(x)))
print(df)
```

Output will look like this:[image]

If you don't use the `str()` like:

```
df['newText'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x:(TextBlob(x)))
```

The ouput will look like:[image]